Manga where MC is a demon king returns to earth to learn he has a Daughter
So this Manga is basically as the title but from what I remember he starts off at a low level demon and climbs the rank, he wants to return to earth because he made a promise with his girlfriend. So he destroys the core and when he returns he goes to his old place to find new people living there looking after his daughter. He has either white or blueish white hair.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What is this "core?"  Is it somehow trapping him, or does it release enough energy when destroyed to send him home?  Also, when and where did you read this?

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

It was all in colour, and the core was something like the core of hell and when he breaks it he’s able to return to earth.
